# same address is allocated to different nodes

Tags: memory

I have to create an array of pointers for rows and columns initially all pointing to null.
The address of the newly created row/column headers are to be inserted into the arrays.
In the result I see that the addresses are repeated in the row and column arrays.

- **Problem: the addresses are repeated in the row and column arrays.**

*I have to mention that I did not use delete (for deallocating the memory yet, because i am confused where to include it whether inside the function or outside).*

I also see that no rowheader is created for the token 2x3y3.

```
First I created an array of pointers  

//allocating row and column pointers, m is number of rows and n is number of columns
- node **rArr = new node*[m+1];
- node **cArr = new node*[n+1];

    void create_array_with_nullp(){


        for(int i=0; i<=m;i++){

            rArr[i]=NULL;
            std::cout<<"row array contents"<<rArr[i]<<'\n';
        }

        for(int i=0; i<=n;i++){

            cArr[i]=NULL;
            std::cout<<"col array contents"<<cArr[i]<<'\n';
        }
    }
```

Then I am creating rowheaders or colheaders for the tokens if not already created through the following function:

```
    void create_n_link_new_node(int a, int b){


        if(a >m || b>n || a<0 || b<0){
            return;
        }

        node * colptr = cArr[b];

        node * rowptr = rArr[a];

        if (rowptr==NULL){

            node * new_rowheader = new node;

            new_rowheader->coefficient = NULL;
            new_rowheader->row = a;
            new_rowheader->column = -1;
            new_rowheader->rowLink = new_rowheader;
            new_rowheader->colLink = new_rowheader;


            rArr[a] = new_rowheader;

            std::cout<<"new row header created"<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "coefficient = "<<new_rowheader->coefficient<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "row = "<<new_rowheader->row<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "column = "<<new_rowheader->column<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "rowLink = "<<new_rowheader->rowLink<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "colLink = "<<new_rowheader->colLink<<'\n';



        }


        if(colptr == NULL){
            node * new_colheader = new node;

            new_colheader->coefficient = NULL;
            new_colheader->row = -1;
            new_colheader->column = b;
            new_colheader->rowLink = new_colheader;
            new_colheader->colLink = new_colheader;



            cArr[b] = new_colheader;

            std::cout<<"new column header created"<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "coefficient = "<<new_colheader->coefficient<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "row = "<<new_colheader->row<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "column = "<<new_colheader->column<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "rowLink = "<<new_colheader->rowLink<<'\n';
            std::cout<< "colLink = "<<new_colheader->colLink<<'\n';



        }
    }
```

The Result is:

```
THE RESULT:
token==5x4y2
coefficient=5
row= 4
col = 2
new row header created
coefficient = 0
row = 4
column = -1
rowLink = 0x100103c10
colLink = 0x100103c10
new column header created
coefficient = 0
row = -1
column = 2
rowLink = 0x100103c30
colLink = 0x100103c30

token==8x4y
coefficient=8
row= 4
col = 1
new column header created
coefficient = 0
row = -1
column = 1
rowLink = 0x100103c50
colLink = 0x100103c50

token==2x3y3
coefficient=2
row= 3
col = 3
new column header created
coefficient = 0
row = -1
column = 3
rowLink = 0x100103c70
colLink = 0x100103c70

token==4xy2
coefficient=4
row= 1
col = 2
new row header created
coefficient = 0
row = 1
column = -1
rowLink = 0x100103c90
colLink = 0x100103c90

token==y3
coefficient=-1
row= 0
col = 3
new row header created
coefficient = 0
row = 0
column = -1
rowLink = 0x100103cb0
colLink = 0x100103cb0

token==5y
coefficient=5
row= 0
col = 1

token==5
coefficient=5
row= 0
col = 0
new column header created
coefficient = 0
row = -1
column = 0
rowLink = 0x100103cd0
colLink = 0x100103cd0
```

why no rowheader is created for token=2x3y3 ?

Finally the addresses stored in Array of pointers are:

```
#Array of row pointers#
- row 0 = 0x100103cb0
- row 1 = 0x100103c90
- row 2 = 0x100103cd0
- row 3 = 0x100103c50
- row 4 = 0x100103c30
#Array of column pointers#
- column 0 = 0x100103cd0
- column 1 = 0x100103c50
- column 2 = 0x100103c30
- column 3 = 0x100103c70

* row 2 is having the same address of column 0,
* row 3 is having the same address of column 1,
* row 4 is having the same address of column 2
```

Comment: same memory address in * row 2 is having the same address of column 0,
* row 3 is having the same address of column 1,
* row 4 is having the same address of column 2

Comment: Thank you Okuma Scott for editing

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to figure out what you're trying to do here. Couple of things that stick out:

Remember that for an array of length m, you can only index from 0 to m-1 (not m). Your loop in `create_array_with_nullp` is going past the end of each of the arrays, corrupting memory.

```
node **rArr = new node*[m];
//...
        for(int i=0; i<=m;i++){  // ouch! should only go to i**<**m
```

---

In `create_n_link_new_node`, did you mean to set the column entry like so:

```
cArr[b] = new_colheader->rowLink;
```

or did you actually mean:

```
cArr[b] = new_colheader;
```

---

Are you intending to have each of colheader and rowheader cross-referenced? If so, you would need:

```
new_colheader->rowLink = new_rowheader;
new_rowheader->colLink = new_colheader;
```

at the end of `create_n_link_new_node`.

Again, not really sure what is trying to be accomplished but those things seem suspect at least.

Comment: I have edited the code "cArr[b] = new_colheader" instead of "cArr[b] = new_colheader->rowLink".  The address of the new_header is to be saved in the array of respective headers.  No rowheader is created for the token 2x3y3.  Finally when I check the array of row & column ..same address is given to some index values.